# Can't connect to my local Apache server on port 8079

Tags: apache, apache-config

I added the following line to my httpd.conf: `Listen *:8079`. But when I navigate to my-local-ip-address:8079 in a browser, it says that the site can't be reached. I also have the line `Listen *:80` in my httpd.conf, and when I navigate to my-local-ip-address:80 in a browser, it works. Why does it only work for port 80 and not for port 8079? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding just a new `Listen` is not enough.

You should check your `<virtualhost>` directives in your apache config files and add the `:port` in them as necessary or you can copy a complete `<virtualhost>` directive with same values but in different port just adding the port like this:

```
 <VirtualHost 10.1.2.3:8079>
```

Check full information in [this](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/manual70/mod/core.html#virtualhost) documentation:

> You can specify a :port to change the port that is matched. If
> unspecified then it defaults to the same port as the most recent
> Listen statement of the main server. You may also specify :* to match
> all ports on that address. (This is recommended when used with
> *default*.)